# xlwings doesn't `get_selection` when run from VBA

Tags: python, xlwings

I write this with some uncertainty about it being the exact problem.  I tried debugging the issue with Spyder, to be more certain with no avail.

The issue is that my script runs well from the interpreter within Spyder when using the `Workbook.set_mock_caller(path)` option, but it doesn't run well from within VBA.

I suspect that `get_selection()` is getting an empty selection, but then I cannot tell for sure because I can't stop the code in the middle.

In any case, my script is my first try to use the package, so it won't be very complicated for anyone who's used it before.  What the function does is to consolidate an Excel selection table by its first column, and add the rest of the columns together.

```
def xl_consolidate():
    thisWB    = xl.Workbook.caller()
    thisSlctn = thisWB.get_selection(asarray=True, atleast_2d=True)

    thisTable = thisSlctn.value
    (m,n) = thisSlctn.shape
    r = thisSlctn.row
    c = thisSlctn.column

    tableDict = dict()
    tableVals = thisTable[:, 1:].astype(np.float)
    for i in range(m):
        thisKey = thisTable[i, 0]
        if thisKey not in tableDict:
            tableDict[thisKey] = tableVals[i, :]
        else:
            tableDict[thisKey] += tableVals[i, :]

    modTable = sorted(tableDict.keys(), key = lambda k:(-tableDict[k][0], k))
    modTable = [np.hstack((key, tableDict[key])) for key in modTable]

    thisSlctn.clear()
    xl.Range((r, c)).value = modTable
```

The error happens in the `sorted` function, it says the following:

```
Error
modTable = sorted(tableDict.keys(), key = lambda k:(-tableDict[k][0], k))
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I did make a selection, when calling the function from VBA.

As an additional question, I would like to know if it is possible to debug the code when run from VBA.  This would help me tackle it.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I only get your error when I don't select any cell. So yes, you're probably right that for some reason it doesn't get the selection. How are you calling `RunPython`? with a button?

However, you're not properly concatenating `modTable`: instead of a list of numpy arrays (something like `[array([ 2.,  8.,  8.]), array([ 3.,  6.,  6.])]`), you should be constructing a single array: `array([[ 2.,  8.,  8.],[3.,  6.,  6.]])` (xlwings with Python3 will even complain if you try to bring over a list of arrays.)

As for debugging: There are two possibilities I can think of (and both wait for better documentation):

1. add some logging statements (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html))
2. use remote debugging from either PyCharm, PyDev (Eclipse) or Visual Studio, some infos can be found [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/146)